# Adjustments to the Fe2(CO)9 structure design with Chemfig

Tags: overleaf, chemfig, chemistry

I'm trying to draw the structure of Fe2(CO)9 using chemfig, but I'm not getting the bridging ligands of the structure quite right.

```
\documenteclass[]{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
            \chemleft{[}
                \chemfig{M
                (<:[3]OC)
                (<[:165]OC)
                (-[5]OC)
                (-[1]\chemabove{C}{O}?[a])
                (<:[:325]\chembelow{C}{O}?[b])
                (<[:295]\chembelow{C}{O}?[c])
                (--[0]M
                (<:[1]CO)
                (<[:15]CO)
                (-[7]CO)
                (-[3]?[a])
                (<:[:215]?[b])
                (<[:225]?[c])
                )
                }
            \chemright{]}
        \schemestop
\end{document}
```

https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Examining-the-structural-changes-in-Fe2(CO)9-under-Safa-Dong/f7d366467cb2af485b628a92f1d349a50f0ced8b/figure/0

Answer (score 4):

According to the figure in the link

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \chemleft{[}
    \chemfig{Fe(-[:230,1.5]OC)(<[:200,1.5]OC)(<:[:160,1.5]OC)(<[:60,2]\charge{90:3pt=O}{C}?[b])(<:[:30,1.1]\charge{90:3pt=O}{C}?[c])(-[:320,1.35]\charge{270:3pt=O}{C}?[a])-[0,2]Fe?[a]?[b,{>}]?[c,{>:}](-[:310,1.5]CO)(<[:340,1.5]CO)(<:[:20,1.5]CO)}
    \chemright{]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, out of curiosity, how can you control the distance between the carbon and oxygen? The two middle Iron CO bonds (not the top bond) look very close between the C and O, do you know how this distance could be controlled to add more space?

Comment: Put more Space With \charge{90:5pt=O}{C}    5pt is the desired space

Answer (score 4):

For absolute vertical alignment of COs you must calculate the bond lengths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{cram width=1ex}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig{
        Fe
        (-[@{op,1}:180,2,,,draw=none])
        (<[:60,2]\chemabove{C}{O}?[co1,4])
        (<:[:30,\fpeval{1/cosd(30)}]\chemabove{C}{O}?[co2,6])
        (-[:-40,\fpeval{1/cosd(-40)}]\chembelow{C}{O}?[co3])
        (<[:130,1.3]OC)
        (<:[:-170,1.3]OC)
        (-[:-130,1.3]OC)
        -[,2]Fe?[co1,4]?[co2,6]?[co3]
        (-[@{cl,1},2,,,draw=none])
        (<[:50,1.3]CO)
        (<:[:-10,1.3]CO)
        (-[:-50,1.3]CO)
    }
    \polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]},height=61pt,depth=39pt,indice={}]{op}{cl}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another approach without calculations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{cram width=1ex}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig{
        \chembelow{C}{O}
        (-[2,1.5,,,draw=none]\chemabove{C}{O}?[co2a,6]?[co2b,6])
        (-[2,2.5,,,draw=none]\chemabove{C}{O}?[co1a,4]?[co1b,4])
        (-[:145,1.5]Fe?[fe]?[co1a,4]?[co2a,6]
        (-[@{op,1}:180,2,,,draw=none])
        (<[:130,1.3]OC)
        (<:[:-170,1.3]OC)
        (-[:-130,1.3]OC))
        (-[:35,1.5]Fe?[fe]?[co1b,4]?[co2b,6]
        (-[@{cl,1},2,,,draw=none])
        (<[:50,1.3]CO)
        (<:[:-10,1.3]CO)
        (-[:-50,1.3]CO))
    }
    \polymerdelim[delimiters={[]},height=59pt,depth=38pt,indice={}]{op}{cl}
\end{document}
```